# How to get Model methods excluding inherited, embeded, generated by rails, getters, setters, validators a and other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I have a question concern a listing of the methods of the model. I'd like to get a list of methods defined in my model, with the exception of getters, setters and methods generated by Rails, validation methods, etc. In general, I depends on the methods defined from start to finish by the programmer.

Use:

```
Model.instance_methods (false) - Object.methods
```

Get methods defined by me as well as the method generated by ActiveRecord. How could I get what I need?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your ~/.irbc

```
# Easily print methods local to an object's class
class Object
  def local_methods
    (methods - Object.instance_methods).sort
  end
end
```

Use the #local_methods method like this:

```
>> class BasketballPlayer
>>   attr_accessor :name
>> 
?>   def champion?
>>     name == "Kevin Garnett"
>>   end
>> end
=> nil
>> kevin_garnett = BasketballPlayer.new
=> #<BasketballPlayer:0x11988f8>
>> kevin_garnett.name = "Kevin Garnett"
=> "Kevin Garnett"
>> kevin_garnett.champion?
=> true
>> kevin_garnett.local_methods
=> ["champion?", "name", "name="]
```

Source : http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/159806033/irb-script-console-tips